# AJAX requests are being cancelled after HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

My XMLHttpRequests are being cancelled, yet still seem to successfully work (data gets to the server). Another question recommended looking into the chrome events for a reason, it seems to cancel right after `HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS`

Here is the request event, and insight as to what might be causing this, or further troubleshooting I can try?:

```
t=1125 [st= 0] +REQUEST_ALIVE [dt=250]
t=1125 [st= 0] URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE [dt=0]
t=1125 [st= 0] +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB [dt=250]
--> load_flags = 33024 (MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
--> method = "PUT"
--> priority = "LOW"
--> upload_id = "0"
--> url = [Redacted]
t=1125 [st= 0] +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE [dt=1]
t=1125 [st= 0] DELEGATE_INFO [dt=1]
--> delegate_info = "extension Tampermonkey"
t=1126 [st= 1] -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
t=1126 [st= 1] HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND [dt=0]
t=1126 [st= 1] HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_ENTRY [dt=0]
t=1126 [st= 1] HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY [dt=0]
t=1126 [st= 1] HTTP_CACHE_READ_INFO [dt=0]
t=1126 [st= 1] URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE [dt=0]
t=1126 [st= 1] +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST [dt=198]
t=1126 [st= 1] HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_STARTED_JOB
--> source_dependency = 82675 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=1324 [st=199] HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
--> source_dependency = 82675 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=1324 [st=199] -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=1324 [st=199] +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST [dt=0]
t=1324 [st=199] HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
--> PUT /users/[Redacted] HTTP/1.1
Host: [Redacted]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 4545
X-NewRelic-ID: UwUDUlFADQEGUlFb
Origin: [Redacted]
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: /
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: [Redacted]
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: [1850 bytes were stripped]
t=1324 [st=199] HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_BODY
--> did_merge = false
--> is_chunked = false
--> length = 4545
t=1324 [st=199] -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=1324 [st=199] +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS [dt=51]
t=1324 [st=199] +HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS [dt=51]
t=1374 [st=249] CANCELLED
t=1375 [st=250] -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
--> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
t=1375 [st=250] URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE [dt=0]
t=1375 [st=250] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Comment: My guess is that your response headers are messed up

Comment: Sadly I have no control over the response. There are similar requests that where not made by myself that do work, I've mimicked them exactly as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell
Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: @AdarshKonchady Sadly I have not, the requests are still being cancelled, yet somehow changes are made anyways based on my request. I've opted to contact the devs of the service I'm modifying, waiting on a response (Could take months knowing their ticket turnaround).

Comment: I was getting the same error. I just figured out why. In my AJAX call using 'JQuery', a 'timeout' of 3000 ms was specified. So any request taking longer than 3000ms was getting automatically cancelled. PS: Even in my case, request used to get cancelled after HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error in `chrome://net-internals/#events`. In my case, the AJAX request was of the following form: 

`$.ajax({ ... timeout: 3000 // coming dynamically in my case ...});`

Hence all requests taking longer than 3000ms were getting automatically cancelled.

Now the solution for you depends on your application whether you want to increase the timeout on the client-side or improve the service on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue. Finally it turned out that the AJAX request (from UI code) was wrongly setting timeout to 3 sec instead of 30 sec. Updating the timeout fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case the same request was being executed **TWICE** (from somewhere else in the code). So the second request cancels the first one, yet data gets back from server OK because the 2nd request succeeds. Sheesh!!!